# Most simple way of generating if-else from compile-time types

Tags: c++, c++14, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am using C++14. I want to generate in the easiest way this code structure for a set of types known at compile-time:

```
if (myinstance.type() == typeid(T)) {

}
else if (myinstance.type() == typeid(U)) {

}...
```

I have a typelist:

```
using MyTypes = std::tuple<int, float, OtherType, OneMoreType>
```

I want to do like this:

```
template <class TList>
void generateIfElses(Object & myinstance);
```

And use like this:

```
generateIfElses<MyType>(instance);
```

I have a solution but I find it quite dirty: it implies a helper struct with 2 specializations plus a function with std::index_sequence support.

What is the simplest way to achive this code structure from a typelist?

Comment: Can you not skip the if/else structure and just rely on overloading to perform the type-specific behaviour? i.e., void do_stuff(T thing) {...} void do_stuff(U thing) {...}` etc

Comment: Why do you need if/else blocks and typeid anyway? Just declare some template function specializations that will handle particular type of that list.

Comment: @lxop I want to add members to a typelist (maybe more later). I do not want to start to add n overloads for a code template that is exactly the same all the time. Basically I need to cast to a type and try if my runtime type belongs to one of the types in that typelist. When it does, an action is taken. No, I do not want to use overloading actually and make boilerplate for each new type I support. I want to just add it to the typelist.

Comment: What is Object? Is it anything like std::variant or std::any?

Comment: And what will the if-else chain do in the blocks?

Comment: How is adding to an overload list different from adding to any other form of "list of actions selected by type"?

Comment: If I add an overload, for each overload I have to add boilerplate for the if (...). If I use a typelist the boilerplate is generated for me and I just have to add a type. Besides that, I also need those types somewhere else and more code is generated in different places.

Comment: @SebastianRedl basically I am trying to find the correct way to cast back a type that comes from somewhere else. Think of an any variable that must recover back its type.

Comment: That sequence of if/elses doesn't do anything.  So an empty program solves your problem.  Probably you intend to do something in the conditions for some purpose, but that is not evident in the question: clarify in question, not comments.  As a guess you really want a variant or something similar.

Comment: @GermánDiago But how do you get the result of the cast out?

Comment: @SebastianRedl I do not. I do a casting of something and assign to an object inside the function. It returns void. The example code is simplified.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show code that actually does something. Code that does nothing tells nothing about the problem. Anyway it looks like you need something like std::variant and std::visit or their Boost counterparts.

Comment: Does [`std::tuple_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, there are better approaches for checking your type than using a bunch of if-else statements, but if you really wish to go down this route, here is some code to do just that. I have left some parts empty for you to fill in depending on what action needs to be taken when the type is found. The code uses the boost.mp11 library (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html))

```
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>

using namespace boost::mp11;

template <class TList, class Size = mp_size<TList>>
struct ifelse {

    using head_type = mp_first<TList>;
    using tail_type = mp_pop_front<TList>;

    template <class X>
    static void call(X& x) {

        if(x.type() == typeid(head_type)) {
            // your object type is found, do something interesting here
        }
        else ifelse<tail_type, mp_size<tail_type>>::call(x);
    }
};

// specialisation for empty typelist
template <class TList>
struct ifelse<TList, mp_size_t<0>> {

    template <class X>
    static void call(X& x) {
        // your object type was not found in the typelist, deal with it here
    }
};
```

And you can use it like this:

```
ifelse< std::tuple<int, float, double> >::call(instance);
```